# why doesn't pkg-config output the "-l" in front of the lib names?

Tags: linux, pkg-config

When I use pkg-config --libs , the output contains many references to libraries. However, some of these libs do NOT have the "-l" in front of them so the linker does not know what to do with the name.  For example, I will get the output:  stdc++   instead of   -lstdc++

What would cause pkg-config to do this?

Also, where does pkg-config get its information? The man page says it uses .ps files in the "prefix" directory. But where are these prefix directories?

-Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` can be set for additional paths to search for `*.pc` files. You can query the default paths with:

> pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config

The `--libs` output is determined by the `Libs:` line in the `.pc` file; usually with something like:

> Libs: -L${libdir} -lfoo

Perhaps the `.pc` file you are referencing is not correctly constructed?